# unixODBC C++ documentation...?

Tags: c++, documentation, unixodbc

I cannot find any.

All I found is this: http://libodbcxx.sourceforge.net/ but this is not the right documentation for me. I got a UnixODBC library for C++, and cannot find any docs

I have this in the headers:

```
/*!
 * \file
 *
 * \author  Peter Harvey 
 * \author  \sa AUTHORS file
 * \version 2
 * \date    2007
 * \license Copyright unixODBC-CPP Project 2003-2009, LGPL
 */
```

But the documentation in sourceforge is totally different - the macro-s (or whatever are the things like `SQL_SUCCEEDED` ) are the same, but the classes are named different, For example, the class in `ODBCStatement.h` is `ODBCStatement`, not `odbc::Statement`, also `odbc::ErrorHandler` is `ODBCHandle`, etc. I have some strange member functions in class `ODBCStatement` like: `doBindParameter`, `doPrepare`, `doExecute`, etc and google knows nothing about them...........

Any ideas?

P.S. I'm maintaining a product, where the code is not written by me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's documentation related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is *NO* such documentation. I contacted Peter Harvey, he advised (what I thought at the beginning) just to watch what his wrapper does in each function and watch the documentation for *unixODBC* - the **`C`** version.

The other option is to rewrite the software, using the `sourceforge` wrapper, as it seems to be well-documented.